# cudnn without any framework

Tags: cudnn, no-framework

Does anyone have an idea, what is matched wrong. 
It compiles without any error, etc., but the Output goes always from Predict class 5 to 3 to 1 and doesnt change.

[Code](https://github.com/Fandavina/Praxisprojekt)(important here PropagationHelper&Network&Layer):

Output:

Update Weight(Value of ConvGradConv is to huge!)
[image]

Networkflow(first 5 and last 5 data in each layer)
[image]

Okay one Error corrected(FullyBackward used inchannel insteed of inputsize), but there must be another one with the ConvLayer.